# remote connection to hdfs aws - connection refused

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-ec2, hdfs

I was able to create a single node hadoop cluster on AWS EC2. I saved a filed (sample.txt) in there which I am trying to access remotely through my application. However, the connection is refused.

I am able to view the file on `http://ec2-...:50070` and everything seems to be running fine.

Security for the EC2 is set to

Type | Protocol | Port Range | Destination/Source

All traffic | All | All | 0.0.0.0/0

jps

```
13168 SecondaryNameNode
12977 DataNode
12821 NameNode
13449 NodeManager
14393 Jps
4585 JobHistoryServer
13322 ResourceManager
```

core-site

```
<property>
   <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
   <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
</property>
```

hdfs-site

```
 <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop/.../namenode</value>
  </property>

 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop/.../datanode</value>
 </property>
```

I am trying to load hdfs file from aws and do something with it.

```
val hdfsLocation = "hdfs://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8020/tmp/sample.txt"

val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("sample")
      .getOrCreate()

val sample = spark.read.textFile(hdfsLocation)
```

**ERROR**

> Using Spark's default log4j profile:
>   org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties Exception in thread "main"
>   java.net.ConnectException: Call From sample-linux/127.0.1.1 to
>   ec2-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8020 failed on connection exception:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see: 
>   http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:731)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1474)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1401)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:752)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1977)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1118)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1400)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:359)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:348)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)  at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:348)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.text(DataFrameReader.scala:623)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.textFile(DataFrameReader.scala:657)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.textFile(DataFrameReader.scala:632)
>     at aws1$.main(aws1.scala:22)    at aws1.main(aws1.scala) Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused     at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:609)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:707)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:370)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1523)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1440)   ... 31 more

Please let me know if i am missing any additional information. 
This is the first time I am working with Hadoop and AWS. I appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm guessing that you never opened port 8020 on the AWS VPC. Also, please never use localhost for a Hadoop config...

Comment: Not really clear why you're not using EMR anyway

Comment: I thought that All traffic would open all the port range (All) would do the trick. I was following a tutorial and used localhost, i will look into changing it

Comment: It's definitely not recommended to open all traffic to an unsecured AWS machine, but okay. In any case, your tutorial was probably about install Hadoop locally. Not within AWS and making it remotely accessible. There's so many automated tools to provision clusters nowadays, I'm still curious why you'd do it manually. At least outside of a VM or your local computer for a single node. Also, Spark can read directly from S3, if that's all you want to do

Comment: Well, i need to read from HDFS and so i thought that using an EC2 instance and installing hadoop would do the job as long as I can read and write. However, I am not able to read and I don't know what write will be either now. Is there any other, pref free way, I can set up hadoop on AWS and make it easy for me to connect. This is just a trial project, just to get used to AWS and HADOOP. I will be deleting and making new t2 micro instances anyway. But for now I need a way to connect to the files remotely.

Comment: Need to read from HDFS because... why? S3 is a compatible hadoop filesystem https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3

Comment: If all you need is a free Spark environment on AWS, I would probably recommend you use Databricks. I just don't see why you need HDFS or any Hadoop specific needs here.